# How do I find duplicate values in a SQL Server table?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

My SQL Server 2008 database has a table called `Reading` with columns `Timestamp` a DateTime value and `Probe_id` which is a foreign key column to the `Probe` table.

My database has unfortunately got some duplicate values in the `Reading` table I wish to remove but I am struggling with the query to find them.

I thought something like this would find the duplicates:

```
select * from Reading where Probe_id = Probe_id and Timestamp = Timestamp;
```

Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH    Duplicates
      AS (SELECT    Probe_id,
                    Timestamp,
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Probe_id, Timestamp ORDER BY Probe_id, Timestamp) AS [RowNumber]
          FROM      Reading
         )
DELETE  FROM Duplicates
WHERE   Duplicates.RowNumber > 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Group by the columns making the records duplicates and then count how much every group has

```
select Probe_id, Timestamp, count(*) as num_of_duplicates
from Reading 
group by Probe_id, Timestamp
having count(*) > 1
```